# Установка Visual Basic 6

Tags: windows, visual-basic

Где можно найти Visual Basic 6 под Win7?

Answer (score 2):

Поддержка Visual Basic 6 давно прекращена Microsoft, хотя он и будет исполняться на Windows 7. Сейчас найти его можно на старых выпусках MSDN для подписчиков. Может еще здесь ([Центр ресурсов по Visual Basic 6.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/vbrun/default.aspx)) что-то полезное найдется. Если Visual Basic 6 не нужен для поддержки унаследованных приложений, лучше установить и использовать [Visual Basic 2010 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-basic-express).